# How to obtain a random word using function and dictionary? (Python 3)

Tags: function, random, python-3.x, dictionary

The user has to select a category. And from there, the program has to generate a random word from the category list. If the user selected an invalid category, the program will prompt the user to choose a category again (loop the askCat function again).

```
import random

#Make word dictionary
wordDict = {'Animals':['Giraffe','Dog','Dolphin','Rabbit','Butterfly'], \
            'Fruits': ['Apple','Pineapple','Durian','Orange','Rambutan'], \
            'Colours': ['Red','Blue','Yellow','Green','Purple'], \
            'Shapes': ['Heart','Circle','Rectangle','Square','Diamond']}

#Determine word category and random word
def askCat (wordDict):
    category = str( input ("To start the game, please choose a category: \n Animals (a), Fruits (f), Colours (c), Shapes (s) "))
    print()
    if category == 'a':
        print ("You chose the Animals category.")
        cat = (wordDict['Animals'])
    elif category == 'f':
        print ("You chose the Fruits category.")
        cat = (wordDict['Animals'])
    elif category == 'c':
        print ("You chose the Colours category.")
        cat = (wordDict['Animals'])
    elif category == 's':
        print ("You chose the Shapes category.")
        cat = (wordDict['Animals'])
    else:
        print ("You entered an invalid category. Try again!")
        print()
        askCat(wordDict)
    return random.choice(cat)

#Print random word
randWord = askCat(wordDict)
print (randWord)
```

When on the first try, the user enter a valid category, the program works just fine. However, the problem I'm facing is that, when the user enter an invalid category the first time, and when he enter a valid category the second time, the program don't work anymore. 
Please do help! Thanks (:

Comment: Careful, you're always picking 'Animals', even with fruits, colours and shapes.

Comment: You should use a while loop instead of using recursion, that's bad practice (and where the bug is actually).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
else:
    print ("You entered an invalid category. Try again!")
    print()
    askCat(wordDict)
return random.choice(cat)
```

In the else branch, you are recursively calling the function again—which is okay—and then you discard its return value and return `cat` instead which, in this call of the function, was never set.

Instead, you should return the value from the recursive call:

```
else:
    print ("You entered an invalid category. Try again!")
    print()
    return askCat(wordDict)
return random.choice(cat)
```

That way, when you call it recursively, the result from that call will be used, and not the one you tried to get from the current `cat`.

Furthermore, in each of your branches, you are doing `cat = (wordDict['Animals'])`; you probably want to change that so you actually get fruits for `f` etc.

And finally, while using recursion is *okay*, it’s not the best way to handle this. Recursion always has a maximum depth it can into, so in the worst case, a user could keep answering the wrong thing increasing the recursion stack further, until the program errors out. If you want to avoid that, you should use a standard loop instead:

```
cat = None
while not cat:
    # You don’t nee to use `str()` here; input always returns a string
    category = input("To start the game, please choose a category: \n Animals (a), Fruits (f), Colours (c), Shapes (s) ")
    print()
    if category == 'a':
        print("You chose the Animals category.")
        cat = wordDict['Animals'] # no need to use parentheses here
    elif category == 'f':
        # ...
        # and so on
    else:
        print("You entered an invalid category. Try again!")
        # the loop will automatically repeat, as `cat` wasn’t set

# when we reach here, `cat` has been set
return random.choice(cat)
```

Answer (score 2):

In your function `askCat`, if the user first enter a wrong category, you call again `askCat`. However, you don't return the value returned by that call.

Replace (in the function `askCat`):

```
askCat(wordDict)
```

to:

```
return askCat(wordDict)
```

However, I would strongly recommend you to use a while loop instead.